# How to stop leafpad from throwing error "can't save config file - /home/pi/.config/leafpad/leafpadrc"

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and while I prefer vim for most things, sometimes I use leafpad.

leafpad works just fine.  The only annoyance is that it usually opens up half off-screen and must be dragged into the working area.

Then, upon exit, it is leaving behind an annoying error message that says:

> leafpad: can't save config file - /home/pi/.config/leafpad/leafpadrc

How can I make this error message go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is an ownership issue with that particular file.

These two commands fixed it:

```
sudo chown pi ~/.config/leafpad
sudo chown pi ~/.config/leafpad/leafpadrc
```

It is now completely gone.

The best part is now it remembers where it was in the desktop when it was last closed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ownerhsip and permissions with my `pathlld` tool:

```
[from Github][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this error would suddenly appear, as it has on my system.

It can be fixed by a change the permissions to the file, which will then work for all users.

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/.config/leafpad
sudo chmod 777 ~/.config/leafpad/leafpadrc
```

(While 777 may be overdoing the permissions, I doubt if any serious security breach would be possible.)

This is better than than SDsolar's answer of changing the owner to a specific user, or even group, as that could risk causing problems with later software updates.